# Convert negative integer to positive integrer using casting

Tags: c, casting

I want the following idea: I have `short a = -4;` and I have an `unsigned short b = (unsigned short)a;`
When I `printf("%hu", b)`, why doesn't it print `4`? How can I convert a negative integer to a positive integer using casting?

Comment: You don't.  That's not how casting works.

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit more so I can understand it? Thanks

Comment: Because the meaning of a cast is *not* to compute the absolute value.  The meaning of a cast is to convert one type to another, generally keeping the same value.  In two's complement arithmetic, the number -4 is represented by a bit pattern which, if treated as a plain binary number, has the value 65532.  So that's probably what the cast will give you.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use a cast?

Comment: So it is impossible to do it by casting? the reason I want to use a cast is to undesratnd better how cast works

Comment: @Tenko yep i'm afraid you can't do that.

Comment: @Tenko It's true that casting a floating-point number to an integer throws away the fractional part, and therefore changes the value.  You probably thought that casting a negative number to unsigned would throw away the `-` sign.  But it just doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Tenko If you want to fully understand casting, it's a surprisingly broad topic.  It's also generally recommended *not* to use explicit casts very often.  In modern C, the number of places where you might need an explicit cast is quite small.  These days, most of the time, an explicit cast indicates someone doesn't quite know what they're doing, and may be hiding an error.

Comment: @SteveSummit yeah, that is what i thought. I continue to missunderstand it. If I cast 167.98 to int , the new value will be 168, so why many people told me that the value is the same, the value has changed. It means that the binary number is the same but the form it is shown changes?

Comment: @Tenko If you cast 167.98 to int, the new value will be 167, not 168.

Comment: @Tenko If you wanted to ask the broad question, "What are all the different cases for what a cast can do?", I wouldn't stop you, and you might get some good answers.  There's quite a bit of good information at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942159/need-some-clarification-regarding-casting-in-c).  I see a few other candidates while doing a Google search for "[what are the rules on casting C site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+are+the+rules+on+casting+C+site%3Astackoverflow.com)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`short` and `unsigned short` are normally 16 bit integers. So limits are -32768 to 32767 for the signed version (`short`) and 0 to 65535 for `unsigned short`. Casting from signed to unsigned just *wraps* values, so -4 will be casted to 65532.

This is the way casting to unsigned works in C language.

If you accept to use additions/substractions, you can do:

```
65536l - (unsigned short) a
```

The operation will use the `long` type (because of the `l` suffix) which is required to be at least a 32 bits integer type. That should successfully convert any negative short integer to its absolute value.

Comment: if I cast -4 I obtain 65632 and later if I operate 65632 - 65628 I obtain 4, so can I automate it so if the user introduces -5 it shows 5 casting it?

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that this rule is asymmetric.  Converting from signed to unsigned always wraps to the range of the unsigned, but it is implementation-defined whether converting from unsigned to signed does the same when the starting value is outside the range of the signed type.

Comment: @Tenko, the combination of operations you describe is equivalent to -4 - 2 * (-4), so yes, you can cover additional negative integers that way.  For example, `b = (unsigned short) a - 2 * (unsigned short) a`.  But that is not the same as absolute value because it does not leave positive inputs unchanged.  And it is not *just* casting.

Comment: Actually you can change it to casting in both directions: cast "-1" to unsinged which will give you 65535 (for unsigned), subtract "a" and add 1 :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the *absolute value* of the number, not a cast. In C we have the [`abs` / `labs` / `llabs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs) functions for that, found in `<stdlib.h>`.

If you know ahead of time that the value is negative, you can also just negate it: `-a`.

Comment: Yeah, but I dont want to use the absolute value method, I want to do it by casting it

Comment: @Tenko Ok, but just because you want to use a hammer to paint your wall doesn't mean you can do it.

Comment: @orlp Just like painting a wall with a hammer, you can do it but you won't like what you get. Hence, the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

If you were instead just looking to get the absolute value, you should have used the `abs()` function from `<stdlib.h>`.

Otherwise, when you make such a cast, you trigger the following conversion rule from C17 6.3.1.3:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type. 60)

Where foot note 60) is important:

> 60. The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression.

Mathematical value meaning we shouldn't consider wrap-around etc when doing the calculation. And the signedness format (2's complement etc) doesn't matter either. Applying this rule, then:

- You have mathematical value `-4` and convert from `signed short` to `unsigned short`.
- We add one more than the maximum value. That is `-4 + USHRT_MAX + 1`, where `UINT_MAX` is likely 2^16 = 65535.
- `-4 + 65535 + 1 = 65532`. This is in range of the new type `unsigned short`.
- We got in range at the first try, but "repeatedly adding or subtracting" is essentially the same as taking the value modulo (max + 1).

This conversion is well-defined and portable - you will get the same result on all systems where `short` is 16 bits.

Comment: Firstly,I do not understand what wrap-around means. Secondly, In the last point "We got in range at the first try" this means that if the number was -67865 it would have made the folowing calculation: first calculation -67865 + 65535 +1= -2329 second calculation: -2329 + 65535 + 1 = 63207 and now there is no third calculation because now it is in range, is this correct?

Comment: @Tenko Wrap-around is what you get when going out of range on an unsigned integer type. It's what it sounds like, given `unsigned short x = 65535; x++;` you are guaranteed a wrap-around to zero. As opposed to signed integer overflow which is undefined behavior. The note about mathematical value means that among other things we shouldn't consider the maximum range of a variable during the calculation, only when we compare the result against the valid range.

Comment: @Tenko "Wrap-around" is what a car's [odometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odometer) does when it rolls over from 99999 to 00000.  Or what a clock does when it goes from 12:00 to 1:00.  Or what a clock does if you're setting it backwards and it goes from 1:00 back to 12:00.  The official term is "[Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)".